# Вывести записи из базы данных в список

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Написала одно простое приложение, и решила попробовать что-то посложнее.

Задумка такая: Приложение будет содержать список из рецептов блюд. В общем у меня получилась БД с таблицей bluda и полями id, bludo, recept, like (поле избранное), img (картинка)

В качестве списка решила использовать RecyclerView

Читала что хорошим тоном является создание отдельного класса Contract. У меня получился такой

Contract.java

```
public final class Contract {
    private Contract() {}

    public static abstract class Bluda implements BaseColumns {
        public static final String TAB_BLUDA = "bluda";

        public static final String COL_BLUDO = "bludo";
        public static final String COL_RECEPT = "recept";
        public static final String COL_IMG = "img";
        public static final String COL_LIKE = "like";
    }
}
```

Также получился класс DBHtlper (который я нашла и адаптировала под себя на просторах стеловерфлоу)

```
public class DBHeler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_PATH;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "bluda.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public SQLiteDatabase database;
    private Context myContext;

    public DBHeler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
        try {
            DB_PATH = myContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).toString();
            createDataBase();
            openDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Cursor getBluda() {
        return database.query(Contract.Bluda.TAB_BLUDA,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor getFavoriteBluda() {
        return database.query(Contract.Bluda.TAB_BLUDA,
                null,
                Contract.Bluda.COL_LIKE + " = 1",
                null,
                null, null, null);
    }

    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if (!dbExist) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase(){
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
        try {

            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }
        catch (SQLiteException e) {
            // база не существует
        }
        if (checkDB != null) {
            checkDB.close();
        }
        return checkDB != null;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);

        String outFileName = DB_PATH;

        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DB_PATH, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if(database != null)
            database.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

Т.е. в классе DBHelper имеем два курсора. Как эти курсоры сунуть в RecyclerView?

Я читала про contentprovider, про CursorLoader, но ничего не поняла толком. Подскажите пожалуйста как двигаться дальше? Какой следующий шаг. Не игнорьте бедную девушку)

Answer (score 0):

Следующим шагом является созданием [курсор адаптера](https://gist.github.com/skyfishjy/443b7448f59be978bc59).

А вообще бы, я сразу смотрел в сторону ORM, например OrmLite. С ними будет проще работать

Comment: А можно вкраце что такое ORM?

Comment: ORM позволяет работать с объектами, то есть сохраняешь объект, и получаешь объект

Comment: Аа поняла спасибо.

Comment: Я бы уж тогда советовал noSQL [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest) или для простых применений -
 [ObjectBox](http://objectbox.io) или там гугловский  [Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html), если непременно ORM нужен, но никак не ORMLite //